# Add density curve to percentage histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a histogram with percentages on the Y axis:

```
    df <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(100))
    ggplot(df, aes(x = V1)) +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count..)/sum(..count..)))+geom_density()
```

I tried to add a density curve using geom_density() but it appears to be on the wrong scale for the percentages. How can I fix this?

[image: curve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..density..`

### Code

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = V1)) +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))+
  geom_density()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: How do I preserve the Y axis to keep the percentages?